# I need answer of one jade agent to depend on information from others and don't know how to do it

Tags: agents-jade

I'm new to jade and I have 5 agents in eclipse that have formula for finding an average and the question is how to send information from agent to this formula for calculation? 
I'll be glad if someone can help me with this.
For example, there is one of my agents. There's no formula, because I don't know how to represent it. This is math expression of it: n+=alfa(y(1,2)-y(1,1))

```
public class FirstAgent extends Agent {
private Logger myLogger = Logger.getMyLogger(getClass().getName());

public class WaitInfoAndReplyBehaviour extends CyclicBehaviour {

    public WaitInfoAndReplyBehaviour(Agent a) {
        super(a);
    }

    public void action() {
        ACLMessage  msg = myAgent.receive();
        if(msg != null){
            ACLMessage reply = msg.createReply();

            if(msg.getPerformative()== ACLMessage.REQUEST){
                String content = msg.getContent();
                if ((content != null) && (content.indexOf("What is your number?") != -1)){
                    myLogger.log(Logger.INFO, "Agent "+getLocalName()+" - Received Info Request from "+msg.getSender().getLocalName());
                    reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.INFORM);
                    try {
                        reply.setContentObject(7);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    myLogger.log(Logger.INFO, "Agent "+getLocalName()+" - Unexpected request ["+content+"] received from "+msg.getSender().getLocalName());
                    reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.REFUSE);
                    reply.setContent("( UnexpectedContent ("+content+"))");
                }

            }
            else {
                myLogger.log(Logger.INFO, "Agent "+getLocalName()+" - Unexpected message ["+ACLMessage.getPerformative(msg.getPerformative())+"] received from "+msg.getSender().getLocalName());
                reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.NOT_UNDERSTOOD);
                reply.setContent("( (Unexpected-act "+ACLMessage.getPerformative(msg.getPerformative())+") )");   
            }
            send(reply);
        }
        else {
            block();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: The question is how to represent the formula in java? Or how to aggregate this information from your agents?

Comment: @nikelyn It's about how to aggregate information from agents

Comment: maybe you should create agent-agregator that will send request to your 5 agents and handle responces (substitute in the formula)?

Comment: @nikelyn sadly it's forbidden by the rules of my task, i can't have supreme agent,than it is not a consensus administration, this formula should find approximate average for every agent and not all of them can talk to each other

Comment: I probably understood you wrong. you want to access to the number of each agent to find average for every of them, but you cannot handle the responces with supreme agent, right?. Do you have access to  AgentController fo your agents? maybe AgentController.putO2AObject will help you. you can create common environment for your agents as well.

Comment: @nikelyn Thankx, it helped

Answer (score 0):

So from what I can make out you want to (1) send a formula/task to multiple platforms, (2) have them performed locally, (3) and have the results communicated back.

I think there are atleast two ways of doing this:

1. The first is sending an object in an ACLMessage using Java Serialisation. This is a more OOP approach and not very "Agenty".
2. The second being the cloning or creating a local task agent.

Using **Java SerialZation**. (Solution 1)
[image]

Create an object for the calculation

```
class CalculationTask implements serialization
{   int n;    
    int calculate(){
    n+=alfa(y(1,2)-y(1,1));
      }
}
```

send the calculation object via ACLMESSAGE from the **senderAgent**.

```
request.setContentObject(new CalculationTask())
```

recieve the calculation object by **recieverAgent**  and perform calculation on the object. Then response setting the complete task in the response.

```
CalculationTask myTask = request.getContentObject();
myTask.calculate();
ACLMESSAGE response = request.createReply();
response.setContentObject(myTask());
response.setPerformative(ACLMESSAGE.INFORM)
send(response)
```

The **senderAgent** then receives the complete job.
ACLMESSAGE inform = getMessage();

```
CalculationTask completeTask = inform.getContentObject();
completeTask.process()
```

Creating local **Task Agents** (Solution 2)
The Agent Orientated way of doing it would be to launch a task agent on each platform. Have each task agent complete the task and respond appropriately.

[image]